# Create a query to determine which sub_genres come from which regions

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

```
SELECT Sub_Genre.sgid, Sub_Genre.sgname, Region.rname 
FROM Sub_Genre AS S, Region AS R
JOIN Band_Styles AS bSty ON bSty.sgname=S.sgname
JOIN Band_Origins AS bOri ON bOri.bname=bSty.bname
JOIN Country AS C ON C.cname=bOri.cname
JOIN Region ON R.rname=C.rname
ORDER BY S.sgid;
```

I am trying to Create a query to determine which sub_genres come from which regions.
I keep getting an Error Code 1054. Unknown column 'Sub_Genre.sgid' in 'field list'

Comment: You should select from `S`, not `Sub_Genre` in the first line, also from `R`, not `Region`

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix explicit and implicit joins. Use standard, explicit joins consistently.

Table `region` appears twice in the query, first in an implicit join with an alias, and then in a standard join without an alias. This is most likely not what you want.

Columns in the `select` clause are prefixed with the entire table name, while the table are aliased in the `from` clause: this is not supported.

This would be a cleaner way to express the logic:

```
select s.sgid, s.sgname, r.rname 
from sub_genre      s
join band_styles    bsty on bsty.sgname = s.sgname
join band_origins   bori on bori.bname = bsty.bname
join country        c     on c.cname = bori.cname
join region         r     on r.rname = c.rname
order by s.sgid;
```

This fixes the syntax problems. Whether this gives the correct results or not is something else: you did not share the structures and data you are working with, so I cannot tell.